# SSL/TLS CipherSuite TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL

Tags: encryption, tls, hmac

CipherSuite TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL means no encryption no mac
Then why it is standardized?What for?
And popular browser and Server support it?

Comment: No handshake with no encryption and no MAC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL is specified and is the initial state of a TLS
>   connection during the first handshake on that channel, but must not be
>   negotiated, as it provides no more protection than an unsecured
>   connection.

TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL (TLS 1.1) is used to check if TLS connections are possible, and to simulate a handshake. It can also be used to switch cipher suites, and indicates the start of a new TLS connection. IIRC it is not used much and will been removed later by TLS 1.3 draft.

Comment: At the start of a new handshake, messages are sent in cleartext. To properly form the TLS message , the cipher TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL is used.